# How to compute the set of polygons from a set of overlapping circles?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, area, computation

This question is an extension on some computation details of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles).

Suppose one has a set of (potentially overlapping) circles, and one wishes to compute the area this set of circles covers. (For simplicity, one can assume some precomputation steps have been made, such as getting rid of circles included entirely in other circles, as well as that the circles induce one connected component.)

[image]

One way to do this is mentioned [in Ants Aasma's and Timothy's Shields' answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles), being that the area of overlapping circles is just a collection of circle slices and polygons, both of which the area is easy to compute.

[image]

[image]

The trouble I'm encountering however is the computation of these polygons. The nodes of the polygons (consisting of circle centers and "outer" intersection points) are easy enough to compute:

[image]

And at first I thought a simple algorithm of picking a random node and visiting neighbors in clockwise order would be sufficient, but this can result in the following "outer" polygon to be constructed, which is not part of the correct polygons.

[image]

So I thought of different approaches. A Breadth First Search to compute minimal cycles, but I think the previous counterexample can easily be modified so that this approach results in the "inner" polygon containing the hole (and which is thus not a correct polygon).

I was thinking of maybe running a Las Vegas style algorithm, taking random points and if said point is in an intersection of circles, try to compute the corresponding polygon. If such a polygon exists, remove circle centers and intersection points composing said polygon. Repeat until no circle centers or intersection points remain.
This would avoid ending up computing the "outer" polygon or the "inner" polygon, but would introduce new problems (outside of the potentially high running time) *e.g.* more than 2 circles intersecting in a single intersection point could remove said intersection point when computing one polygon, but would be necessary still for the next.

Ultimately, my question is: **How to compute such polygons?**

PS: As a bonus question for after having computed the polygons, how to know which angle to consider when computing the area of some circle slice, between theta and 2PI - theta?

Answer (score 2):

Once we have the points of the polygons in the right order, computing the area is a [not too difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327761/2144669).

The way to achieve that is by exploiting planar duality. See the Wikipedia article on the [doubly connected edge list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) representation for diagrams, but the gist is, given an oriented edge whose right face is inside a polygon, the next oriented edge in that polygon is the reverse direction of the previous oriented edge with the same head in clockwise order.

Hence we've reduced the problem to finding the oriented edges of the polygonal union and determining the correct order with respect to each head. We actually solve the latter problem first. Each intersection of disks gives rise to a quadrilateral. Let's call the centers C and D and the intersections A and B. Assume without loss of generality that the disk centered at C is not smaller than the disk centered at D. The interior angle formed by A→C←B is less than 180 degrees, so the signed area of that triangle is negative if and only if A→C precedes B→C in clockwise order around C, in turn if and only if B→D precedes A→D in clockwise order around D.

Now we determine which edges are actually polygon boundaries. For a particular disk, we have a bunch of angle intervals around its center from before (each sweeping out the clockwise sector from the first endpoint to the second). What we need amounts to a more complicated version of the common interview question of computing the union of segments. The usual sweep line algorithm that increases the cover count whenever it scans an opening endpoint and decreases the cover count whenever it scans a closing endpoint can be made to work here, with the adjustment that we need to initialize the count not to 0 but to the proper cover count of the starting angle.

There's a way to do all of this with no trigonometry, just subtraction and determinants and comparisons.

Comment: I'm very uncertain to have understood your explanation, but simply put, are you maybe saying I should exchange undirected edges between circle centers and intersection points for pairs of directed arcs precising which side is inside a polygon, which can be determined when computing intersection points between pairs of circles? And afterwards merge said "inside sides" of arcs to obtain my polygons?